# Fresh 20.04 - second monitor is detected but can't be used

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 and I can't make my second monitor work. I've switched from `nouveau` to `NVIDIA` 460 and I can't make it work.

The monitor is detected but when I try to set "join displays" and click on `apply`, I can see that it immediately jumps back to the default settings.

I thought that I can set it up in `NVIDIA` settings but there is no such option.

When I run `sudo nvidia-settings` it returns this:

```
milano@milano-lenovo:~$ sudo nvidia-settings

(nvidia-settings:2456): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:18:19.023: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should have been installed along with this driver at /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.

** Message: 16:18:19.079: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 16:18:19.079: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

I'm desperate since I can't figure out what todo. Do you have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you haven't installed the correct driver version. Run `ubuntu-drivers devices` and install the recommended driver version instead.